# Popup Images in Ms. Excel

Tags: excel

Some of you, who are reading this, may find this question quite trivial but this is a specific use-case question that popped up in my head randomly and not being able to find the solution is not sitting well with me.

With that said, here's the problem:

1. I want to input image in an excel sheet. In a cell particularly - as data. *If this is possible, a helpful link or a nudge in the right direction is appreciated.*
2. That is the general gist of it. I just want pictures in cells(They can be linked to cells too; but they have to be locally available and available offline).

> Onto the issue with those problematic solutions:
>   
> - The issue with (1) is that pictures do not sit inside cells in excel like they do in some online worksheets. I haven't found one and I'd like to hear alternatives and/or your experiences.
>   
> - The issue with (2) is that it is a multi-step solution. I stumbled upon a solution but can't seem to reduce the steps any further. *[I found this video where it shows it is possible by adding pictures as comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZU52uN6Qvg). However, there is no shortcut that I know of, to do this. Is it possible to create one? Or does it exist natively?*

*Additional information for the curious:* Whats the particular use?

- Nothing much. I watch a lot of shows and I wanted a way to track them down. [MAL](http://myanimelist.net) doesn't have lists for shows. Too bad. So I decided to keep things offline for a solution and to track upcoming seasons.

> **Any alternative is welcome.** (If it isn't obvious, I'm referring to a macro based solution. However, I'd like to avoid it as best as possible and keep things simple; but if it can't be helped - oh well.)

Comment: Interesting question, but it probably belongs on superusers rather than here (http://superuser.com/ )

Comment: I think I have already done something like that. I am sure that I have attached pictures as files in a sheet but i don't know if it is possible with specific cells. I will find my vba code and post it as an answer here but propably you will have to imrpove it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done:

```
Private Sub photo1_Click()
    Dim ftopen As Variant

    'get file name from open file dialog box.
    ftopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose file to attach")

    'if no file chosen then close sub
    If ftopen = False Then
        MsgBox ("No file selected!!!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'insert file into sheet.
    Worksheets(3).OLEObjects.Add Filename:=ftopen, Link:=False, _
         DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:="Photo1"   
End Sub
```

This will add a picture as file into the excel sheet. I suppose you can change that a bit to store the picture in a specific cell.

I have assigned this sub into a button to do the work. If I find anything else regarding this I will update my answer with further information.

**EDIT:**

Ok. So here is some more info on this and on what I have done:

Firstly here you can find more info regarding the vba function OLEObjects.Add:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195728.aspx

As far as I understand you can add almost any file you want and you can choose the location to add it in the sheet (size also)(check top,left,width parameters)

Secondly here is some pictures of the result I got with this:
My button with a label acting as counter (incrementing as you add photos)
[image]

And the result in the sheet when a photo is uploaded:
[image]